# Resque 2.0 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redistogo

I want to be able to run Resque 2.0 with Heroku and Rails but there doesn't seem to be any good tutorial/documentation about it.

It seems I might need something like `RedisToGo` but not sure whether it is a good practice to use without it or not. I'm also concerned that as I'm based in Australia, whether RedisToGo is still a good option.

Has anyone done a good Rails 4, Resque 2.0 implementation with Heroku lately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a good tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque) for you

We run Resque on Heroku - Resque is basically the "backend" engine which allows you to send queue data to the likes of Redis. Redis is just a way to collect that queue data & store it for future use

Comment: Would u recommend having `RedisToGo` or just in Heroku? Also that link is for Ruby not Rails and version of Resque is not 2.0. So if I use Resque 2.0 wouldn't it be different?

Comment: I would highly recommend using Redis (it's like RAM for your app). Yes I thought about that (seems Resque version is 1.25). Bottom line is that Heroku uses AWS instances - so if you wanted a truly bespoke system, you'd would be suited to signing up for AWS & installing Resque 2.0 separately :)

Comment: `RedisToGo` is a third party for hosting Redis. `http://redistogo.com/` Should I use it or is it better to setup Redis on Heroku and us it?

Comment: I don't think you can use Redis on Heroku itself -- it has to be done through a third party :) We use RedisCloud, but all the Redis offerings are basically the same thing!